# Storing access token in Redis

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I am using Redis to store the access token. I want to know if I need to encrypt the token before saving to redis. If yes then please explain why.I am using C# and Stackexchange.Redis library.

Comment: Why do you want to encrypt ? Do/Would you encrypt while saving to another database such as RDBMs?

Comment: My concern is what if an attacker got access to the cache and then he/she has access to all the tokens.

Comment: Don't forget to set a password on your Redis instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is stated in the security section of [redis documentation](https://redis.io/topics/security)

> Redis is designed to be accessed by trusted clients inside trusted environments. This means that usually it is not a good idea to expose the Redis instance directly to the internet or, in general, to an environment where untrusted clients can directly access the Redis TCP port or UNIX socket.

So it is better to secure the instance instead of every individual data in it. Redis doesn't support encryption, as you mentioned you need to handle in application layer. You need to wrap the commands by encrypt/decrypt methods.

For extra security, i think you must use `authentication` by setting password at configuration file. It can be a long one and will be saved in the configuration file so every command will require `auth` as a prerequisite.

If your concern is security of the instances communicating with redis, that's another topic. `auth` will not help just like encryption secret. Since both secrets are in the hand of attacker, he can retrieve the original data.